# Seleccionar consulta con JComboBox

Tags: java, mysql

Hola tengo un problema quiero hacer que de un JComboBox yo pueda seleccionar un articulo de mi BD y me hace la consulta de cargar bien y todo pero cuando quiero seleccionar otro articulo la consulta que tengo para que se mire el stock de dicho articulo me falla aqui les dejo el codigo si alguien me dice porfa :(

CON ESTO CARGO LOS DATOS (ESTO SIENTO YO QUE ESTA BIEN)

```
//limpio el combobox y el textfield
txtProducto.removeAllItems();
txtInventario.setText("");
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conne=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);
    Statement consulta=(Statement) conne.createStatement();

    //consulta sql a la tabla 
    ResultSet rsinventario = consulta.executeQuery ("select Descripcion from inventario");


    // Se recorre el ResultSet inventario.
    while (rsinventario.next()) {
        txtProducto.addItem((String) rsinventario.getObject("Descripcion"));
    }

    ResultSet rscantidad = consulta.executeQuery ("select Cantidad from inventario");
    while(rscantidad.next()) {
        txtInventario.setText((String) rscantidad.getObject("Cantidad"));
    }

    conne.close();
} catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error sql no se pueden leer datos");
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al leer la base de datos");
}
```

Y CON ESTO HAGO LA CONSULTA QUE HACE QUE CUANDO YO SELECCIONO ALGUN ARTICULO ME MUESTRE EL STOCK DE DICHO EN UN JTEXTFIELD(ME SALE UN ERROR CON EL WHERE LO CORRE BIEN MI NETBEANS PERO EN LA CONSOLA SALE ERROR MAS ABAJO LO DETALLO MEJOR)

```
ConexionesMySQL mysql = new ConexionesMySQL();
Connection cn = mysql.conectar();
try {
    Statement st= cn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from inventario where Descripcion="+txtProducto.getSelectedItem()+"");
    while(rs.next())
    {
    txtInventario.setText((String) rs.getObject("Cantidad"));
    }
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Hojas_Envio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

txtProducto es el nombre de mi jcombobox quiero que la consulta me la haga de lo que se seleccione y cuando el programa se corre y se selecciona sale este error en consola

(Calcetas es el nombre de un articulo que hay en mi BD si funcionara me deberia salir que tengo 56 en stock :(  )

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Calcetas' in 'where clause'

vengo comenzando en esto de la programacion y la verdad si me dijeran en que falle me seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: el problema es que los valores tipo varchar y similares deben escribirse entre comillas simples